# How to access script1.js file block variables in script2.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, data-structures

script1:

```
let id;
search_input.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{
        async function searchItem(API){
                    const response=await API
                    const data=await response.json()
                    let ItemList=data.results
                    for(condition){
                        // API Process===========
                        //GET Id
                        id=API_per_element_id  // I WANT TO ACCESS THIS variable. in script2.js file
                    }
        }
        let  API=`apiurl&query=${e.target.value}`
        searchItem(API)//API=MOVIEAPI
}
```

script 2:
`console.log(id)`

I want to access id variable in
Script.js file

I want to console id variable in
Script2.js file

Comment: For that you need to export `id` from script1 and import into script2.
`in script1 last line add => export { id };`
`in script2 first line add => import { id } from './script1.js';`

Comment: I think it is possible with the help of cookie or local storage